# How to send category based order emails in magento?

Tags: magento

I have two root categories in my magento site. One is "Home Products" and the other is "Office products".

These two root categories have some sub categories also.
I want to send "Home Products" related orders to this email address "email_home@example.com",

 And to send "Office Products" related orders to this email address "email_office@example.com".

How will I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to write own Observer to order.

```
sales_order_place_after
```

event suits best for your purpose.

If buyer can add to shopping cart items only from 1 cateogry.

Your module should:

1. Get order via observer.
2. Get order first item and get it's category
3. Choose email based on category

Send email

```
 public function sendOrder(){
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder(); 
            ...
            //Implement logic here
            ...

    $emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
                    ->loadDefault('your_template');                            
    $emailTemplateVariables = array();
    $emailTemplateVariables['order'] = $order;      
    $emailTemplate->setSenderName('Your shops name');
    $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail('addres@from.com');
    $emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject(Subject');
    $emailTemplate->send('to@addres.com','Name', $emailTemplateVariables);          
 }
```

**Update 1**

First of all I insist that you see the link I provide in the comments area.

Then:
To create module:

1. Create in app/etc/modules/ Company_Module.xml file. With the content similiar to this one:

   true
                   local
               
           
       
   This eill tell magento, that in app/code/local/Company/Module there is something interesting to watch.
2. Create proper folder and file structure.
   For you module I think it would be enough:

   ```
   Company
   -Module
   --etc
   ---config.xml
   --Model
   ---Observer.php
   --Helper
   ---Data.php
   ```
3. Magento should know everything about your module. Moreover you should define observer for event.
   Important note: we will catch Magento's event. Not ours.

config.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Company_Module>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
            </Company_Module>
        </modules>
        <global>
            <models>
                <company_module>
                    <class>Company_Module_Model</class>
                </company_module>
            </models>
            <helpers>
                <cmod>
                    <class>Company_Module_Helper</class>
                </cmod>
            </helpers>
            <events>
                <sales_order_place_after>
                    <observers>
                        <sales_order_place_after_observer>
                            <class>company_module/observer</class>
                            <method>handleOrder</method>
                        </sales_order_place_after_observer>
                    </observers>
                </sales_order_place_after>
            </events>
        </global>
    </config>
```

Data.php - It is empty but it should be.

```
    class Company_Module_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract{

    }
```

Observer.php

```
    class Company_Module_Model_Observer{
            public function handleOrder($observer){
                    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();   
                            ...
                            //Implement logic here
                            ...

                    $emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
                            ->loadDefault('your_template');                            
                    $emailTemplateVariables = array();
                    $emailTemplateVariables['order'] = $order;        
                    $emailTemplate->setSenderName('Your shops name');
                    $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail('addres@from.com');
                    $emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject(Subject');
                    $emailTemplate->send('to@addres.com','Name', $emailTemplateVariables); 
            }
    }
```

Comment: Where should I write this code? Means in which file? I am new magento. Please explain your answer.

Comment: If you are new in magento than things are a little more complicated. Checkout this link http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method

Comment: I think by default, magento send email to the admin on the order completion. So where is that file? Will writing the email logic in that file solve my problem? Because that will be easy for me? Any idea plz?

Comment: If you wish, you want to change core file, which is not a good practice. Order e-mail is sent in Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php and function is sendNewOrderEmail. But I warn you, that this is not a very good practice - to change core.

Comment: If I place the order.php in app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/order.php and then change the file then will it not be fine?

Comment: I guess it would be ok. Because you don't change core file. But you should test, how it works. And perhaps I don't know if this model is what you need.

Comment: Can you please tell me some steps about creating the event for my purpose. What steps should I take?

Answer (score 0):

@Jevgeni (and anyone else needing the link), the Link for Magento has moved

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method

Comment: This should have been posted as a comment

Comment: I don't have the 50 rep to add the comment below, i figured once the link was updated I could delete this message