# Magento: Send email based on Attribute after sale

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to send an email to a custom email address based on an attribute set in the administration back-end, I am inexperienced with Magento and this is a little beyond me.  I have no idea where to go with the logic for the order to get what i need (and if several items are ordered, used/new/poster then I need to send 3 emails, so will be a foreach

I know I need to single out each item, fetch its attributes and run my foreach... just lost on the Magento skills to get it done.

I started with this questions answer and got a good start:
[How to send category based order emails in magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265989/how-to-send-category-based-order-emails-in-magento)

**(Edits 1 & 2: changed contents of Observer.php file)**

**(Edit 3: added config.xml, Data.php, Company_Module.xml contents)**

{MagentoDir}app/etc/modules/Company_Module.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>core</codePool>
        </Company_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

{MagentoDir}app/code/local/Company/Module/etc/config.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Module>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Company_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <company_module>
                <class>Company_Module_Model</class>
            </company_module>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <cmod>
                <class>Company_Module_Helper</class>
            </cmod>
        </helpers>
        <events>
            <sales_order_place_after>
                <observers>
                    <sales_order_place_after_observer>
                        <class>company_module/observer</class>
                        <method>handleOrder</method>
                    </sales_order_place_after_observer>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_after>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

{MagentoDir}app/code/local/Company/Module/Helper/Data.php file:

```
<?php

class Company_Module_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}

?>
```

{MagentoDir}app/code/local/Company/Module/Model/Observer.php file:

```
<?php

class Company_Module_Model_Observer
{
    public function handleOrder($observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();   
        // logic to find what was ordered
        $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();

        $attributeType = array();
        foreach($items as $itemId => $item)
        {
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());

            //Once we have the product, we search the attribute set
            $attributeSetId = $product->getAttributeSetId();

            // get attribute
            $type = $product->getDataSource();

            var_dump($type);
            Mage::log('My text' . $type);

            // get item info and create array for each attribute
            $attributeType[$type][] = array(
                'name'      => $item->getName(),
                'unitPrice' => $item->getPrice(),
                'sku'       => $item->getSku(),
                'ids'       => $item->getProductId(),
                'qty'       => $item->getQtyToInvoice()
            );
        }

        foreach($attributeType as $orderType => $orderGroup)
        {
            // send email based on what was ordered
            $emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('my_template');                            
            $emailTemplateVariables = array();
            $emailTemplateVariables['order'] = json_encode($orderGroup);        
            $emailTemplate->setSenderName('Site');
            $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail('sales@site.com');

            switch ($orderType)
            {
                case 'used':
                    $emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject('Used order at Site');
                    $emailTemplate->send('me@site.com', 'Site', $emailTemplateVariables);
                    break;
                case 'poster':
                    $emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject('Poster order from Site');
                    $emailTemplate->send('me@site.com', 'Site', $emailTemplateVariables);
                    break;
                default:
                    $emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject('New order at Site');
                    $emailTemplate->send('me@site.com', 'Site', $emailTemplateVariables);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

It will be 3 separate email addresses, just going to me for testing

**(Edit 4: System log file contents)**

{MagenetoDir}var/log/system.log

```
2013-08-02T16:55:07+00:00 DEBUG (7): Dhtechnologies_Ediconnectorbase_Model_Observer::processDocuments finished
2013-08-02T16:56:01+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : attributes construct error  in /www/html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
2013-08-02T16:56:01+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): <xml version="1.0"?>  in /www/html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
2013-08-02T16:56:01+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():                   ^  in /www/html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
2013-08-02T16:56:01+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Couldn't find end of Start Tag xml line 1  in /www/html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
2013-08-02T16:56:01+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): <xml version="1.0"?>  in /www/html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
2013-08-02T16:56:01+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():                   ^  in /www/html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
2013-08-02T16:56:01+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document  in /www/html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
2013-08-02T16:56:01+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string(): <xml version="1.0"?>  in /www/html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
2013-08-02T16:56:01+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: simplexml_load_string():                   ^  in /www/html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
```

I have read the walk through at:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method

I have googled the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, decided to place my code on the "success.phtml" page instead of adding it as a "mod"

copied success.phtml to my template directory

```
/app/design/frontend/{theme}/{theme}/template/checkout/success.phtml
```

at the bottom of the page I added

```
if($orderNumber = $this->escapeHtml($this->getOrderId()))
{
    $item_arr   = array(); $x = 0;

    $body  = "Order Number: <strong>"   . $orderNumber  . "</strong><br />";

    // fetch the order based on the id
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderNumber);

    // get order total value
    $orderValue = number_format ($order->getGrandTotal(), 2, '.' , $thousands_sep = '');

//  $body .= "Order Value: $"           . $orderValue   . "<br />";
    $body .= '<br />';

    // Get shipping method  
    $shipping_method = $order->_data["shipping_description"];   

    // Get ship-to address information  
    $shipping_address_data = $order->getShippingAddress();  

    $body .= "Shipping Method: <strong>". $shipping_method  . "</strong><br />";

    // Get payment information  
    $payment_method = $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle();  

    $body .= "Payment Method: <strong>" . $payment_method   . "</strong>*<br /><br />";

    // get order item collection
    $orderItems = $order->getAllItems();

    // Output the ship-to address information  
    $body .= $shipping_address_data['firstname']    . " ";  
    $body .= $shipping_address_data['lastname']     . "<br />";  
    $body .= $shipping_address_data['street']       . "<br />";  
    $body .= $shipping_address_data['city']         . ", ";  
    $body .= $shipping_address_data['region']       . " ";  
    $body .= $shipping_address_data['postcode']     . "<br />";  
    $body .= $shipping_address_data['country_id']   . "<br /><br />";

    $table_start .= '
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>';

    $used_body = ''; $posters_body = '';
    foreach ($orderItems as $item)
    {
        $product_id     = $item->product_id;
        $product_sku    = $item->sku;
        $product_name   = $item->getName();
        $_product       = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
        $cats           = $_product->getCategoryIds();
//      $new_or_used    = $_product->getAttributeText('new_or_used');
        $quantity       = rtrim($item->getQtyOrdered(), '.0000');
        $price          = number_format($item->getPrice(), 2);
        $category_id    = $cats[0]; // just grab the first id
        $category       = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id);
        $category_name  = $category->getName();     // Movies, Gaming, Music, Posters

        if(stripos($product_sku, 'Used'))
        {
            // duplicating items?
            if(!in_array($product_sku, $item_arr))
            {
                $item_arr[$x]   = $product_sku; $x++;

                $used_body .= "
        <tr style=\"border-top: 1px solid #000;\">
            <td style=\"padding: .25em;\">$product_id</td>
            <td style=\"padding: .25em .5em;\">
                SKU: <strong>$product_sku</strong> 
                Category: <strong>$category_name</strong> <br />
                <strong>$product_name</strong>
            </td>
            <td style=\"padding: .25em; text-align: right;\">$quantity</td>
            <td>$ $price</td>
        </tr>";

            }
        }

        else if($category_name == 'Posters')
        {
            // duplicating items?
            if(!in_array($product_sku, $item_arr))
            {
                $item_arr[$x]   = $product_sku; $x++;

                $posters_body .= "
        <tr style=\"border-top: 1px solid #000;\">
            <td> $product_id </td>
            <td style=\"padding: .25em 1em;\">
                SKU: <strong>$product_sku</strong> 
                Category: <strong>$category_name</strong> <br />
                <strong>$product_name</strong>
            </td>
            <td> $quantity </td>
        </tr>";

            }
        }
    }
    $table_end .= '</table><br />* If "Payment Method" is <strong>Check / Money order</strong>, please ensure payment is received BEFORE shipping product.';

    $poster_mail= ($poseter_body != '') ? $body . $table_start . $posters_body . $table_end : NULL;
    $used_mail  = ($used_body != '')    ? $body . $table_start . $used_body . $table_end    : NULL;

    $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
    $mail->setFromEmail('orders@store.com');
    $mail->setFromName("Store order queue");
    $mail->setType('html');     // You can use html or text as mail format

    if($used_mail != '')
    {
        $mail->setToName('store');
        $mail->setToEmail('me@store.com');
        $mail->setBody($used_mail);
        $mail->setSubject('Used item ordered at store');
    }

    if($poster_mail != '')
    {
        $mail->setToName('store');
        $mail->setToEmail('me@store.com');
        $mail->setBody($poster_mail);
        $mail->setSubject('Poster ordered at store');
    }

    $mail->send();

}
```

I will need to clean it up some, but as is it works for my needs

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Company_Module_Model_Observer  
{
    public function handleOrder($observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
        foreach($items as $item){
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
            //Once we have the product, we search the attribute Data Source
            $dataSource = $product->getDataSource();
            var_dump($dataSource);
        }
```

Comment: So if my attribute is "data_source" and I know its ID is 134, but i need to get its value?

Comment: Ok, I think i got confussed with "based on an attribute set", attribute set is another entity. I just edited the answer

Comment: Altered code above, I have tried a test order with this file (and the other 4 files from the linked page) and I am not getting an email... if you would like I can include the file structure and contents as well

Comment: What are you getting with this: $type = $product->getDataSource();
can you do a var_dump() ? or something to debug

Comment: expored var dump to text file and no file was created

-- $file = "dump.txt"; 
-- $fh = fopen($file, 'w'); 
-- fwrite($fh, implode("\n", $type)); 
-- fclose($fh);

Comment: In Magento, the easy way to debug exporting the data is doing something like this: Mage::log('My text' . $product->getDataSource()); And then you see the output in var/log/system.log

Comment: Okay, updated, added files and full structure of file tree... In the log file there was no instance of "my text" and only 2 lines that mentioned "Observer" -- the file names and folders are all capitalized as stated in the original question, if capitalization matters maybe that is my issue, or maybe I messed up a folder?

Comment: Ok, you need to load the product, check the edited answer. Greetings

Comment: included system.log text from attempt, updated observer.php to show your recommended changes... still not getting email, and nothing in system log... this tells me that it is not initiating the event handler of doing this after an order is placed?

Comment: everything else seems to be showing a full directory structure, but this - <class>company_module/observer</class> - doesn't, is this line correct (in the config.xml file), the full directory structure for this file is Company/Module/Model/Observer

Comment: There is an EDI Connector mod installed if that might cause a conflict, it performs action after order